# Can't display the two float values correctly from pyserial on Arduino's LCD

Tags: serial, python, float

I transported two float values with pyserial to COM3 and Arduino accepted the values.

But it displayed the first value correctly on LCD, the second value can't be read and showed "nan" on LCD.

Python code:

```py
import serial
import struct
ser =serial.Serial("COM3", 115200, timeout=2)

##======Get  Ready================
print("Connecting to Arduino.....")
for i in range (1,10):
    rv=ser.readline()
    print("Loading...")
    #Debug print (rv) # Read the newest output from the Arduino
    print (rv.decode("utf-8")) 
    ser.flushInput()
    sleep(1) # Delay for one tenth of a secon
    Str=rv.decode("utf-8")
    #Debug print(Str[0:5])
    if Str[0:5]=="Ready":  
          print("Get Arduino Ready !")
          break
##------------------------------------------------------
d = 77.25
a = 111.32
ser.write(struct.pack('>2f',d,a))
```

Arduino code:

```c++
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
float x;
byte *xdata = (byte *) & x;
float y;
byte *ydata = (byte *) & y;
int num = 0;
char coor[2];

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); // set the baud rate
  Serial.println("Ready"); // print "Ready" once
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows: 
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
}

void loop(){
  while(Serial.available() > 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      coor[i] = Serial.read();
      }
    if(coor[0] == 'B' ){
      xdata[3] = coor[0];
      ydata[3] = coor[1];
      num = 1;
    } else if(num == 1){
      xdata[2] = coor[0];
      ydata[2] = coor[1];
      num++;
    } else if(num == 2){
      xdata[1] = coor[0];
      ydata[1] = coor[1];
      num++;
    } else if(num == 3){
      xdata[0] = coor[0];
      ydata[0] = coor[1];
      num = 0;
    // use the values
    Serial.write(xdata,4);
    Serial.write(ydata,4);
    lcd.print(x);
    lcd.setCursor(8,0);
    lcd.print(y);
      }
    }
```

The LCD monitor will show 77.25 and nan. It can't show 111.32 correctly.

Comment: you read two bytes if at least one is available. read the two bytes with `Serial.readBytes(coor, 2)`. it will wait for the second byte

Comment: Or wait for there to be 2 bytes available before reading them...

Comment: sorry,i still can't unserstand the following code," Serial.readBytes(coor, 2) ",where to write.

Comment: I replaced "coor[i] = Serial.read();" with "Serial.readBytes(coor, 2)",but it still can't work.

Comment: and you removed the for loop? https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readbytes/

Comment: No,I deleted the  "for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){ coor[i] = Serial.read(); }" and write "Serial.readBytes(coor, 2);" in while funtion.

Comment: the LCD showed different,the 77.25 became 64.25 on LCD monitor,and the nan became -0.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you read the bytes this way. Your original version was reading only the bytes of the first float into xdata and -1 into ydata. (`read` returns -1 if no data is available, it doesn't wait.) Now when two bytes are read with `readBytes`, first two bytes of the first float are written one into xdata[0] and second into ydata[0].

read first float with `readBytes(xdata, 4)` and the the second with `readBytes(ydata, 4)`